# if $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of V such that $V = U_1 ⊕ W$ and $V = U_2 ⊕ W$, then $U_1 = U_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose nonzero $u_1 \in U_1$ then $u_1 \in V$. Since $U_1 \cap W=\{0\}$ 
>   we must have $u_1 \notin W$. Next since $V=U_2 \oplus W,$ we must have 
>   $u_1 \in U_2$. Similarly suppose nonzero $u_2 \in U_2$ then $u_2 \in V$ 
>   and since $U_2 \cap W = \{0\}$ it follows that we have $u_2 \notin W$ and
>   since $V=U_1 \oplus W,$ then $u_2 \in U_1.$ This completes the proof that
>   $U_1=U_2.$

Does my proof work? Any feedback welcome.

Comment: It does not. $u_1 \notin W$ does not yield $u_1 \in U_2$. Also the statement itself is false.

Comment: this might be true if $\oplus$ denotes orthogonal sum, otherwise even the claim is certainly wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question was prove or give a counter example. I'll have to do some more thinking.. $\oplus$ is direct sum.

Comment: look at $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W $ the linear hull of, say, $e_2$. Now try finding a complementary subspace and ask yourself whether it is unique.

Comment: It's only true if $\dim V=0$ or $\dim V=1$. You get easy counterexamples as soon as $\dim V>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your proof: *since $U_1 \cap W=\{0\}$ we must have $u_1 \notin W$. Next since $V=U_2 \oplus W$ we must have $u_1 \in U_2$.*

Your deduction that $u_1 \in U_2$ is wrong. You can have both $u_1 \notin W$ and $u_1 \notin U_2$. For example take $U_1 = \mathbb {R} e_1$, $U_2= \mathbb {R} e_2$ and $W = \mathbb{R}(e_1+e_2)$.